Shows Deploy option in Streamlit eventhough app is deployed in docker
Streamlit app codes worked fine in local machine and I tested it. After deploying in the docker , I can access the app thorugh localhost.
My question is if app already deployed then why in the browser it shows option "deploy" again? I am confused and want to get rid of that option.


code doesn't know that you deployed it. Besides it may allow to deploy it in different place. You could try to find solution for this - maybe it will need to dig in source code. Frankly, I wouldn't care for this because it can be waste of time.

I followed the documentation from streamlit website. In my case it mandatory because I am going to deploy streamlit apps in production.

You can add this piece of code at the start of your file:
import streamlit as st

st.markdown(
    """
    <style>
        .stDeployButton {display:none;}
    </style>
""",
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

st.header("Main Page")

The "Deploy" button disappears:

However, it will be gone even locally.

I adapted a solution from tonykip I found on the Streamlit Discuss Forum.

In streamlit 1.40.1, this piece of code will help:
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title="Page Title", layout="wide")

st.markdown(
    r"""
    <style>
        .stAppDeployButton {display:none;}
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

st.header("Main Page")


This doesn't look different from an existing answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Use stAppDeployButton instead of stDeployButton.
